# Max on a Long Text data type - in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table I have a list of companies and several fields including a note field. I am attempting to remove duplicates with the same company name and adjusting the information as needed for the rest of the fields using the totals: Group As, Max and Min.

This works on all the fields except the note field and is causing two companies to come up twice since I cannot merge the note field.  The note field is a **Long Text data type** and when I change it to Short Text data type it works and I can do the merge, however it looses a significant part of the note which I need to keep. How can I use a Max function with long text or is there another way around this?

Below is an example:

```
ID          CompanyName           Notes

123         CompanyA
124         CompanyA              Long note goes here. 
126         CompanyB              Note here   
234         CompanyC
```

My Goal is to get it to look like this:

```
ID          CompanyName           Notes

123         CompanyA              Long note goes here. 
126         CompanyB              Note here   
234         CompanyC
```

Comment: Why do you have the same company in the table twice?  That seems like a design flaw.

Comment: Allen Browne has a good general discussion dealing with Access Memo types: [Truncation of Memo fields](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html)

Comment: It is a design flaw built by another company. I'm just trying to fix the historical information so I can put it into the client's new system without the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably not use `MAX` on a text field to eliminate duplicates, because it may pick a wrong item for you. For example, if you feed `'A very good and long note'` and `'Stub'` to a `MAX`, it would prefer `'Stub'`, because it is higher lexicographically.

Perhaps you want to apply `MAX` to the length of the note, rather than the note itself. If you do that, you could find duplicates with a simple query:

```
SELECT c.ID as dup_ID, c.CompanyName as dup_name, c.Notes as dup_Notes
FROM Company c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Company oc
    WHERE oc.CompanyName = c.CompanyName AND LEN(c.Notes) < LEN(oc.Notes)
)
```